# Change XCode 4 Multi-Touch Gestures

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts, gestures

I use [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) to customize the Multi-Touch Gestures I use in OS X.  For example, I like to use three finger swipes up and down to switch between tabs in most applications.  XCode 4 seems to already have three finger swipe up/down bound to "Switch between header and implementation".  Is there a way to turn off that binding in XCode?

Answer (score 3):

I have looked high and low within Xcode 4 and online, and sadly, there seems to be no way to disable the three-finger swipe gesture within Xcode.  As a last resort, I even tried disabling the keyboard shortcuts for `Jump to Next Counterpart` and `Jump to Previous Counterpart` -- but it had no effect on the gesture.

If you are using the tab bar in Xcode 4 and are looking for an easier way to switch between tabs, you can use the default keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> for `Select Previous Tab` and `Select Next Tab`, respectively.

Apple accepts feedback from developers using [this form](http://developer.apple.com/contact/) -- perhaps you can submit a request to make this an option in the next Xcode update.